# The limit of Element Tree on xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I've used Element Tree for a while and i love it because of its simplicity

But I'm doubting of its implementation of x path

This is the XML file

```
<a>
  <b name="b1"></b>
  <b name="b2"><c/></b>
  <b name="b2"></b>
  <b name="b3"></b>
</a>
```

The python code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.findall("b[@name='b2' and c]")
```

The program shows the error:

```
invalid predicate
```

But if I use

```
root.findall("b[@name='b2']") or 
 root.findall("b[c]")
```

It works,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ElementTree provides limited support for XPath expressions. The goal is to support a small subset of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of the core library.

(F. Lundh, [XPath Support in ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm).)

For an ElementTree implementation that supports XPath (1.0), check out [LXML](http://lxml.de):

```
>>> s = """<a>
  <b name="b1"></b>
  <b name="b2"><c /></b>
  <b name="b2"></b>
  <b name="b3"></b>
</a>"""
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> t = etree.fromstring(s)
>>> t.xpath("b[@name='b2' and c]")
[<Element b at 1340788>]
```

Comment: Thanks, well, do you think lxml must be part of python core in the next release instead of Element Tree?

Comment: @HOAINAMNGUYEN: I don't decide that :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [ElementTree documentation on XPath support.](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm):

> ElementTree provides limited support for XPath expressions. The goal is to support a small subset of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of the core library.

You've just discovered a limitation in the implementation. You could use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) instead; it provides a ElementTree-compatible interface with complete [XPath 1.0 support](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).