# python xml - search for attribute with regular expressions

Tags: python, xml, xpath

In my xml file, I have nodes like this:

```
<waitingJobs idList="J03ac2db8 J03ac2fb0"/>
```

I know how to use `.findall` to search for attributes but now, it looks like I would need to use regular expressions because [I can't just use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)

```
root.findall('./[@attrib='value']')
```

I'd have to use

```
root.findall('./[@attrib='*value*']')
```

**QUESTION**

1. Is this possible with `xml.etree`?
2. How do you do this with `lxml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, things like `contains()` and `starts-with()` are not supported by `xml.etree.ElementTree` built-in library. You can manually check the attribute, finding all `waitingJobs` and using [`.attrib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) to get to the `idList` value:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<jobs>
    <waitingJobs idList="J03ac2db8 J03ac2fb0"/>
</jobs>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
value = 'J03ac2db8'
print([elm for elm in root.findall(".//waitingJobs[@idList]") 
       if value in elm.attrib["idList"]])
```

With `lxml.etree`, you can use `xpath()` method and `contains()` function:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

data = """<jobs>
    <waitingJobs idList="J03ac2db8 J03ac2fb0"/>
</jobs>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

value = 'J03ac2db8'
print(root.xpath(".//waitingJobs[contains(@idList, '%s')]" % value))
```

Comment: sigh. I guess it's finally time to move to `lxml`. For how sucky `xml.etree` is, why is it still included in Python? Why isn't `lxml` the default????

Comment: @Adrian well, this is definitely sad, but the beauty of Python is also that huge variety of the third-parties available on the PyPI. A little about why the xpath support is limited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982557/the-limit-of-element-tree-on-xpath. Thanks.