# Find sibling element text value in XML using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using Python 3.7 with Anaconda, and I am trying to get the text value from the XML element following the element with text = CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO.  So in this case I would like to return '779'.

As can be seen with the following XML segment, these tags are not unique and have no names or attributes, so only the contained text can be used to locate the data.

```
    <CustomField>
        <id>CustomField/63</id>
        <fieldName>CX.WLS.RATETYPE</fieldName>
        <stringValue>FIX30</stringValue>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
        <id>CustomField/64</id>
        <fieldName>CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO</fieldName>
        <stringValue>779</stringValue>
        <numericValue>779.0</numericValue>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
        <id>CustomField/65</id>
        <fieldName>CX.PAIRS16</fieldName>
        <stringValue>779</stringValue>
        <numericValue>779.0</numericValue>
    </CustomField>
```

I have tried various forms of this:

`Borrower_FICO = root.find('.//*[fieldName = "CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO"]/following-sibling::node()')`

and..

`Borrower_FICO = root.find('.//*[text() = "CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO"]/following-sibling::node()')`

but can't see to pull the data into my variable `Borrower_FICO`

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: `following-sibling` is not supported by ElementTree. It does work with lxml: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10982557/407651

Comment: As @mzjn suggests - use lxml (specifically lxml.etree since this is an xml file); it then becomes relatively simple (and you don't even need `following-sibling`...)

Comment: thanks, I converted to lxml and got it to work using a loop:  `for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.text == "CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO" :
        find_fico = elem.getnext().text`

Comment: Might as well post the answer for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

`following-sibling` is not supported by ElementTree. It does work with lxm though.

I converted to lxml and got it to work using a loop:

```
for elem in root.iter(): 
    if elem.text == "CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO" :  
        Borrower_FICO = elem.getnext().text
```

Comment: While this works in the case of a simple xml files, you probably are better off sticking to xpath if the file gets more complicated. In this case `Borrower_FICO = root.xpath('//CustomField[./fieldName[.="CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO"]]/stringValue/text()')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Below: (no need for lxml)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><CustomField>
        <id>CustomField/63</id>
        <fieldName>CX.WLS.RATETYPE</fieldName>
        <stringValue>FIX30</stringValue>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
        <id>CustomField/64</id>
        <fieldName>CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO</fieldName>
        <stringValue>779</stringValue>
        <numericValue>779.0</numericValue>
    </CustomField>
    <CustomField>
        <id>CustomField/65</id>
        <fieldName>CX.PAIRS16</fieldName>
        <stringValue>779</stringValue>
        <numericValue>779.0</numericValue>
    </CustomField></r>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
entry = root.find(".//CustomField/[fieldName='CX.PAIR1.BORROWER.FICO']")
print(entry.find('stringValue').text)
```

output:

```
779
```